Google Authentication and Site Ownership Verification for Web App Development
I'm developing a Web app that requires Google authentication for users. I have followed the documentation at Google Shopping Content API Guide to set up authentication using my app's credentials.
Regarding project verification, the documentation mentions verifying site ownership using Google Site Verification. How do we handle this process if we have sub-domains?
Let's say I have a site example.com where I have the required home page, privacy policy, and terms of service pages. I have a sub-domain like dev.example.com that I want to use in the required URL fields. Is there any possible issue regarding this scenario?

Once you verify the naked domain (examle.com), the subdomains are automatically included. Additional verification of subdomains is not required.

Thanks.
And what if the example.com domain is already verified in a gmail id, let's say abc@gmail.com. Now, I want to use another gmail id xyz@gmail.com to use another console app for another purpose with the same domain example.com, it also requires to verify the site ownership in that new gmail id xyz@gmail.com.
Is there any possible conflicts I may face if  the same domain is verified in multiple different active console projects with different gmail ids?

An email address is not the same thing as a domain hostname. The fact you control an email address does not mean you control a domain.
